# How to stop PHPUnit in the middle of tests but still get a list of failures / reports?

Tags: phpunit

We have a test suite that runs 30 or more minutes and it is not uncommon for me to see a situation like this:

[image]

I don't generally want to break on a first failure (`--stop-on-failure`) but in this specific example, I also don't want to wait another 10-15 minutes for the test suite to finish. If I do Ctrl+C, the process stops immediately and I won't see any messages.

I'm specifically interested in the format that PHPUnit uses in the console which I find very useful. For example, logging to a file using `--testdox-text` produces a nice but not very detailed list. Logging with `--log-teamcity` is verbose and quite technical.

Is there a way to see "console-like" PHPUnit messages before the test suite fully finishes?

---

Update: I've also opened an [issue in the official repo](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/issues/3138).

Comment: Did you already have a look at --verbose or --debug?

Comment: @ThomasVdBerge The example above already uses `--verbose` and `--debug` is something slightly different.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you could register a [listener](https://phpunit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/extending-phpunit.html#implement-phpunit-framework-testlistener) in your phpunit.xml file and implement its addFailure() method to display some info in console or a file...